# How to use prompt the user for the location in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Create a report that displays the department name, location, name, job, and salary of those employees who work in a specific location. Prompt the user for the location.

```
SELECT E.EMPNO, 
       E.SAL, 
       D.DEPTNO, 
       D.DNAME, 
       D.LOC 
  FROM EMP E, 
       DEPT D 
 WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO 
   AND D.LOC = & DEPTNO;

Enter value for deptno: 20

old   3: DEPT D WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO AND D.LOC = & DEPTNO
new   3: DEPT D WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO AND D.LOC = 20
DEPT D WHERE E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO AND D.LOC = 20
                                 *
ERROR at line 3:
 ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your column( `D.LOC` ) is of string type. 
So, whether use

- `'&DEPTNO'` quoted as substitution variable and enter `20` or
- `&DEPTNO` non-quoted as substitution variable and enter `'20'`

whenever prompted.

**Edit:**

Depending on the data you shared on the comment below, you need to replace `D.LOC` with `D.DEPTNO` for `WHERE D.LOC = '&DEPTNO'` yielding `WHERE D.DEPTNO = '&DEPTNO'`, and the above issue raised due to this collation( *i.e. collation between two values string versus numeric, LOC vs. DEPTNO respectively* ), and get the query as below :

```
SELECT E.EMPNO, 
       E.SAL, 
       D.DEPTNO, 
       D.DNAME, 
       D.LOC 
  FROM EMP E 
  JOIN DEPT D ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO
 WHERE D.DEPTNO = '&DEPTNO';
```

Comment: after I fixed, there no location shows when I enter the number.

Comment: @YongmingLiu are you sure you have a location with code 20? By the way, what's the data type of the `loc` column ?

Comment: yes it has location     DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

Comment: @YongmingLiu due to your sample data you need to collate d.deptno with '&deptno'